# react-redux-firebase: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux, react-redux-firebase

I am trying to create a simple web application using firestore. I get the above-mentioned error for some reason. Could someone explain what possibly is wrong? And how to go about solving it? I am using react-redux-firebase 2.2.6.

index.js file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./store/reducers/rootReducer";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { reduxFirestore, getFirestore } from "redux-firestore";
import { reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase } from "react-redux-firebase";

import fbConfig from "./config/fbConfig";

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(
      thunk.withExtraArgument({
        getFirebase,
        getFirestore
      })
    ),
    reduxFirestore(fbConfig),
    reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig)
  )
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

The fbConfig.js file. The details have been removed for security reasons I assure all the valid credentials are provided while I try to run the code.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';


var fbConfig = {
    apiKey: //API KEY HERE,
    authDomain: //authDomain here,
    databaseURL: ,
    projectId: ,
    storageBucket: ,
    messagingSenderId: ,
    appId: ,
    measurementId: 
};
firebase.initializeApp(fbConfig);
firebase.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });

export default firebase;
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is with the latest version of react-redux-firebase.
To solve it I installed a previous version. Version 2.8.1 to be specific. It works fine now